# How to remove the `__typename` field from the graphql response which fails the mutations

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, express-graphql

I tried changing the addTypeName: false in the Apollo client in GraphQL

```
apollo.create({
  link: httpLinkWithErrorHandling,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: false }),
  defaultOptions: {
    watchQuery: {
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      errorPolicy: 'all'
    }
  }
```

But it works and it throws the following messages in the console

```
fragmentMatcher.js:26 You're using fragments in your queries, but either don't have the addTypename:true option set in Apollo Client, or you are trying to write a fragment to the store without the __typename.Please turn on the addTypename option and include __typename when writing fragments so that Apollo Clientcan accurately match fragments.
```

,

```
Could not find __typename on Fragment  PopulatedOutageType
```

and

```
fragmentMatcher.js:28 DEPRECATION WARNING: using fragments without __typename is unsupported behavior and will be removed in future versions of Apollo client. You should fix this and set addTypename to true now.
```

even if i change false to true `new InMemoryCache({ addTypename: true }),` the mutations start failing because of the unwanted typename in the mutation

is there any way to resolve this issue

Comment: Asked and answered here: [Apollo boost - \_\_typename in query prevent new mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873741/apollo-boost-typename-in-query-prevent-new-mutation). If you're using a query results as initial state, you'll need to transform it first to strip out the `__typename` fields (and any other fields that may not be valid input fields).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Cleaning Unwanted Fields From GraphQL Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211778/cleaning-unwanted-fields-from-graphql-responses/51380645#51380645)

In the above thread, I have posted the answer for this problem please refer to it

Comment: Probably worth noting that this will likely break caching unless you make adjustments.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2881

Comment: This question was more generalized but got more attention and has a more reviewed answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211778/cleaning-unwanted-fields-from-graphql-responses

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution with the latest Apollo Client consists of using an appropriate `Link` within the apollo client.

Here is an example

```
import { removeTypenameFromVariables } from '@apollo/client/link/remove-typename';

const removeTypenameLink = removeTypenameFromVariables();

import { from } from '@apollo/client';

const link = from([removeTypenameLink, httpLink]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  // ... other options
});
```

A full detail from Apollo docs can be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-remove-typename/)